# Matching two tables with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, scripting

I have a table named 'companies' where I store general information about the companies in Lithuania that i am listing, therefore the columnns are named name, phonenumber, town, zipcode, etc.

But there's also a column called "region" where I didn't fill in anything, upon entering the data in my MySQL Table. Bummer. So that whole column is empty (i.e. none of the rows carry a value in the 'region' field)

However, I have another table, named "regions" - consisting of two columns: region_name & zipcodes - where all the zipcodes of each region in the country is stored, only seperated by a break in the line.

How do I script an update statement that'll fill in the region_name in  the companies-table that corresponds to the zipcodes of each row (i.e. each company)

Example:

A company has a zipcode of 5000 in the table named 'companies' But there is no region listed. The table called "regions" has the zipcode 5000 in a row where the region_name is "Northwest", where the value is clammed in between other zipcodes, seperated by line breaks.

Here's an image of the 'regions' table:

http://i.snag.gy/MRQje.jpg

How do I now script a PHP or SQL statement, that'll fill in "Northwest" for companies that have zipcodes matching that region?

I have made this so far:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE zipcode LIKE '$something_here'")
or die(mysql_error()); if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
} } else { echo "no matches"; }
} else { echo "ingen matches."; }
```

Comment: Share with us what you have tried? You could setup a SQL fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using MySQL LIKE to match zipcodes and assign regions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901697/using-mysql-like-to-match-zipcodes-and-assign-regions)

Comment: Sample data is really helpful for this kind of thing. Also, PostgreSQL tag, huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt you can achieve this in just SQL.

However, on second thought, I don't understand the need of filling in those regions in the `companies` table, you can always find the `region` by querying from the `regions` table:

```
Select c.name, c.phonenumber, c.town, c.zipcode, r.region_name 
from companies c, regions r where r.zipcode like '%' + c.zipcode + '%'
and c.zipcode like '%something here%'
```

Comment: can this be applied even though the zipcodes are seperated by a linebreak ? since you equate the two, there wouldn't be any matches, right ?

Comment: what do you mean by linebreak?

Comment: Try my updated solution. I can't promise it will work because your `regions` table is not in the proper format.

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ 7900 7950 7960 7970 7980 7990 7700 7730 7741 7742 7752 7755 7760 ' at line 1"

Comment: @user3866921 my bad! `+` is used in SQL Server, I cannot remember the syntax for concatenation in mySQL, can you try and fix that part yourself?

Comment: im trying. dots are used in php to connect. looks like this now:

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bede_companies WHERE zipcode LIKE '%".$region_zipcodes."%'")

but doesnt match anything. wtf

Comment: No, you are doing it wrong. It is the other way round, you need to pick the zipcode from the `Companies` and try to find a match in the `regions` table. `SELECT * FROM region_table WHERE zipcode like %(The zipcode in the companies table)%`

Comment: the table named regions, is where i have region names and corresponding zipcodes (seperated by linebreak OR space [not sure about that yet ] )

the table companies, is where i have zipcodes of each company .. like "5000" for Company A, or "6000" for Company B.

I'm attempting to run a SELECT, that identifies all companies that retain a zipcode matching each region. 

$region_zipcodes = "5000 5001 5002 5003 5004";

$company_zipcode = "5002";

the mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bede_companies WHERE zipcode LIKE '%".$region_zipcodes."%'")

Doesn't do anything, since it doesn't match em :( FML

Comment: Of course you won't get the result. $region_zipcodes = "5000 5001 5002 5003 5004", and $company_zipcode = "5002", how do you expect to find a match if you have `WHERE "5002" like "5000 5001 5002 5003 5004"`

Comment: that DOES match.. 5002 matches %5002% - no ?